# Apache - typing without www on my domain does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

When i typed:
`example.com` , my site works, but when i typed `www.example.com` or `http://example.com` it does not work, it give me `This site can’t be reached`.

This is my Apache Configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAlias http://example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What seems to be the problem here? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Makes me think of a DNS issue. Do you have an `A` or `CNAME` entry (plus `AAAA` if the webserver has IPv6 addresses) for `www` in your zone ? A simple test would be to ping `www.example.com` to see if it resolves to an IP address. If still in doubt, show your DNS configuration.

Comment: @Anonymous - i only have an `A` . I don't know how to use a `CNAME`. This is my DNS Settings, i'm using cloudflare - https://www.screencast.com/t/4voqLjWu

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots, try to post **text** only and update your question. Your screenshot does not help unfortunately. There is a `A` record for `www` but no idea what the IP address could be. I am not even sure you are changing the DNS configuration at the right place. The DNS for your domain name could be at the registrar or the webhost. Simple test: if you run a whois query on the domain name: what are the name servers listed for the domain name ? Please update the question with info, rather than in the comments.

Comment: It is probably your browser defaulting to a https connection on port 443 as oppose to port 80. So add a virtual host  like this with port 443.